# How to "rewrite" SHOUTcast stream IP 

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, shoutcast

Usually SHOUTcast radio stations have...

A domain & hosting (Apache): `http://some-domain.com`
And SHOUTcast Server Version 1.9.8/Linux on IP: `x.x.x.x:8000`

User can enter IP in it's preferred player and listen.

I would like to set same thing but in different way, domain+port:

```
http://some-domain.com:8000
```

**How do I ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the domain name resolve to the same IP address as your stream (e.g. `stackoverflow.com:80` or `http://64.34.119.12:80`)

This would mean your HTTP server is running on the same server as Shoutcast which is not necessarily good because each one has the potential to use a lot of resources.

One way to get around that would be to have a router that port forwards port 8000 to one server and port 80 to another.  These systems now have to be on the same network.

Alternatively, you could use DNS and have `shoutcast.yourdomain.com` for example.  That could point to an IP address of a Shoutcast server anywhere in the world or even the webserver itself.